# Выборочный экспорт из БД

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

Добрый день!
Столкнулся с маленькой проблемой, есть 2 БД , с одинаковыми таблицами;
рассмотрим таблицу i_block_elements в первой БД
в которой существуют  5ть полей с данными.
необходимо экспортировать данные из этой таблицы по этим полям. не программно, а в пределах возможности phpmyadmin

выбираю sql запросом: SELECT  pole1, pole2, pole3, pole4, pole5 FROM `i_block_elements` WHERE id=11
 у нас выберается все что мы хотели, но как это экспортировать?, нажимал на экспорт он мне всю таблицу скачивает.

Далее, после того как мы все таки экспортируем выбранные поля, необходимо импортировать во 2ю базу с такой же таблицей и с 2мя из 5ти полями pole1, и pole2 с данными.
Необходимо импортировать так, чтобы те данные что были в pole1 и pole2 обновились (то есть добавились не достающие)а pole3,  pole4 и pole5 добавились  полностью

PS
конец рабочего дня , мозг кипит, надеюсь доступно расписал.заранее огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

ну почему же, можно через view ;)

```
CREATE view tmp_my_view AS SELECT album_id from album_data;
CREATE TABLE new_materialized_view SELECT album_id, 0 as fld1, '' as fld2, null as fld3 from tmp_my_view;
```

смысл: делаем view, туда заносим нужные данные, потом создаем таблицу на основе Вашего view ;)

Comment: через phpmyadmin множно это тоже сделать обычным sql запросом...

Answer (score -1):

через pma по-моему нельзя делать экспорт определенных столбцов. Во всяком случае я не нашел. 
По второй проблеме: в расширенных настройках экспорта есть список "Использовать оператор при сохранении данных:". Выбирите UPDATE.